# Add or Remove Programs process name

Tags: windows-xp, process

Does anyone know what is the process name of 'Add or Remove Programs' applet? I'm using Windows XP + SP2. It hung up and I would like to kill it.

Comment: I think it's `run32dll.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Add/Remove Programs configuration panel (**appwiz.cpl**) is loaded through the shell32.dll, so you can't kill the process without possibly killing off other applications. In other words, it doesn't have a dedicated process.

(To start an instance of it, just type "appwiz.cpl" in the "Run..." command window.)

Comment: thanks, I closed my eyes and killed all run32.dll processes. it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to go to the applications tab, right-click on the application, and click Go To Process.

I tested on my machine, In windows 7 this process was explorer.exe. I killed that process and it closes it out nicely

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately it runs as part of the desktop Explorer.exe instance. the control panel object is called 'appwiz.cpl' and is loaded into the process under the handle 'appwiz.cpl.mui'so if you search for appwiz in Process Explorer you can see which process has included the DLL and who has the handle open to it.

unfortunately I just tested, and forcing the handle closed does not close the window. You will have to kill and respawn the Explorer.exe instance that the library has associate with instead of the applet itself.